# Multiple Screen in AndroidX Preferences issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, androidx, android-jetpack

My goal is to build a multiple preference screen consisting of main preferences *root.xml* and subpreferences *adv_preferences.xml* using AndroidX Preferences. So far the application only consists of a MainActivity and some fragments such as a home screen fragment, MyRootFragment and AdvPreferencesFragment.

[image: Settings Screenshot]

**MainActivity** does not contain any preferences related code.

**MySettingsFragment.kt**:

```
class MyRootFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() { // basic preferences
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root, rootKey)
    }
}
class AdvPreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() { // advanced preferences
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.adv_preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

**root.xml** (basic preferences):

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settings">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="display_text"
        android:summaryOff="Invisible"
        android:summaryOn="Visible"
        android:title="blabla"/>
    <Preference
        app:title="Advanced Settings"
        app:summary="Test for using multiple screens"
        app:fragment="com.example.app.ui.settings.AdvPreferencesFragment"/>
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

**adv_preferences.xml** (advanced preferences):

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Preference
        android:key="preference_key"
        android:title="placeholder"
        android:summary="placeholder" />
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_root_preferences"
    android:name="com.example.app.ui.settings.MyRootFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_preferences"
    tools:layout="@xml/root" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_adv_preferences"
    android:name="com.example.app.ui.settings.AdvPreferencesFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_preferences"
    tools:layout="@xml/adv_preferences" />
```

Everytime I tap *Advanced Settings* the app would crash with the following logcat message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment
>   AdvPreferencesFragment{...} declared target fragment
>   MySettingsFragment{...} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!

How can I fix this? Everything seems to be hooked up correctly in both fragments, xml files and navigation graph.

I already tried to add the following

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.settings, MyRootFragment())
    .commit()
```

to the onCreate() method in MainActivity (as in the Android Jetpack Preference Guide) but this lead to the following crash and message (the app wouldn't even launch anymore):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id …
>   (com.example.app:id/settings) for fragment MySettingsFragment{...}

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/63305040/3894179

Answer (score -1):

```
try use <preference> replace <fragment> in mobile_navigation.xml
```

like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Preference
        app:fragment="com.xxx.mypreference.AdvPreferencesFragment"
        app:key="notification_category"
        app:title="Adv"
        app:summary="Adv">
    </Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```