# PreferenceFragments not in the same FragmentManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, fragment, fragmentmanager

We have a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, and with a tap on a preference, we want to switch from the current `PreferenceFragmentCompat` to a new `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. (To have certain settings on a new screen).

However, regardless of what we have tried, we keep running into the following error:

> Fragment declared target fragment that does not belong to this
> FragmentManager

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_preferences
            )
        )

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onPreferenceStartFragment(caller: PreferenceFragmentCompat, pref: Preference): Boolean {
        val args = pref.extras
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            classLoader,
            pref.fragment)
        fragment.arguments = args
        fragment.setTargetFragment(caller, 0)
        // Replace the existing Fragment with the new Fragment
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
        return true
    }
}
```

**PreferenceFragement1.kt**

```
class PreferencesFragment1 : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences1, rootKey)
    }
}
```

**PreferenceFragment2.kt**

```
class PreferenceFragment2 : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences2, rootKey)
    }
}
```

**Preferences1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Category"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false">

        <Preference
            app:key="pref2"
            app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
            android:title="Open"
            app:fragment="com.testapp.ui.preferences.Preference2"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Preferences2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The stacktrace shows the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Preference2{496ebb9} (1b91d8df-58c0-485a-96f9-d392fcef528b) id=0x7f09008d} declared target fragment Preference1{b6337c1} (97aa1b0e-d5fa-4995-b0ba-e89ad0ea5ce0) id=0x7f09008d} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1255)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:136)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1989)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

We are using `androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1`.
Can some give us a concise explanation what exactly is causing this problem, and how we can solve it?

We already looked at the following (related) posts, without any success:

- [Fragment declared target fragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045788/fragment-declared-target-fragment-that-does-not-belong-to-this-fragmentmanager)
- [How to open a new PreferenceFragment from current one, using the new Android-X API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723661/how-to-open-a-new-preferencefragment-from-current-one-using-the-new-android-x-a)
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a Fragment via the navigation graph, it is a child fragment of the `NavHostFragment`. It specifically is **not** the activity's `supportFragmentManager`. This is why the target fragment isn't found - you're using the wrong FragmentManager.

However, you should not use `app:fragment` or `onPreferenceStartFragment` when you're using Navigation. Instead, your `PreferencesFragment1` should set a click listener on your Preference and have it call `navigate()` directly.

```
class PreferencesFragment1 : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences1, rootKey)
        findPreference<Preference>("pref2")?.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
            // Use whatever ID that is associated with
            // PreferenceFragment2 in your navigation graph
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.pref2)
        }
    }
}
```

**Preferences1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Category"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false">

        <Preference
            app:key="pref2"
            app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
            android:title="Open"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for this answer! Big fan of yours by the way, as a Google employee, I wonder if the docs could be updated sometime? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings 
The overview section talks about using PreferenceFragmentCompat, from the Jetpack library, yet when we get to the above section on sub Preference Screens, we're talking about the "old" way with overriding the Activity method etc., and there's no guidance on achieving nested settings screens in Jetpack/Navigation Component world.

Comment: I literally searching for this answer for 3 hours. I even did some research on android sample repo https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples. Someone should put this in the official docs